# How can I add mesh texture based on my applied shader? (glTF file)

Tags: mesh, texturing, shaders, gltf

So I used [this YouTube guide](https://youtu.be/CAtiX1po4Bk) to import league of legends models from the game so that I can SLA 3D print them with insane detail.

The problem is that the object itself looks like this:

[image]

Blah.

And with the textures looks like this:

[image]

The shading itself adds a lot of depth and detail to areas and looks a lot cooler to print. This is what the texture/shader looks like:

[image]

My question is, **is there a procedural way that I can use these textures and their color to add physical depth to the mesh?** There are also areas that I want to leave alone flat, such as the face and stomach, so it would also be cool to know how to exclude those areas.

I appreciate any help. I am brand new to Blender and installed it simply for this project. THANK YOU!

Comment: You could use the texture in a _Displacement_ modifier as greyscale height map. This can work but in some places, but maybe not all. Maybe you manually create a greyscale image in Photoshop or other image editor, to change some parts that don't look correctly when displaced. Afterwards when satisfied with the result you can apply the _Displacement_ modifier to keep the physical changes in the mesh. I don't know from the screenshot how high the mesh resolution is, maybe you also need a _Subdivision Surface_ modifier before the _Displacement_ to get better results.